# Keycloak throws UnknownHostException when hosted in private network and using Azure AD as oauth provider

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, keycloak

I am using Keycloak as an identity broker to Azure AD id provider. When I hosted it on localhost. The auth was working fine.
When I hosted keycloak on an intranet server (corporate network) with private IP 10.x.x.x. I also have the new broker's redirect URL got added in the Azure AD app.

It now throws an error when authenticating through Azure AD.

```
Unexpected error when authenticating with identity provider
```

I am running Keycloak in standalone mode. The above error doesn't come when I login using keycloak managed identities.

I suspect as per the logs the private IP is not being recognized. How do I solve this? Is the fixing required at Keycloak or Azure AD side? Please help.

Thanks

Logs:

```
    20:51:27,723 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-80) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=my-realm, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=10.x.x.x, error=identity_provider_login_failure

20:51:50,728 ERROR [org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider] (default task-86) Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: java.net.UnknownHostException: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server (login.microsoftonline.com)

    at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)

    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)

    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)

    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1277)

    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)

    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)

    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)

    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:112)

    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)

    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)

    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)

    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)

    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)

    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)

    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)

    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)

    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)

    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)

    at org.keycloak.broker.provider.util.SimpleHttp.makeRequest(SimpleHttp.java:223)

    at org.keycloak.broker.provider.util.SimpleHttp.asResponse(SimpleHttp.java:181)

    at org.keycloak.broker.provider.util.SimpleHttp.asString(SimpleHttp.java:173)

    at org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider$Endpoint.authResponse(AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider.java:470)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:543)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:432)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:393)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:395)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:364)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:150)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:110)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:141)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:104)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:245)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:61)

    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)

    at org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:41)

    at org.keycloak.services.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.filter(AbstractRequestFilter.java:43)

    at org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.doFilter(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:39)

    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)

    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)

    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)

    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)

    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)

    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)

    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)

    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)

    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)

    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)

    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)

    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)

    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)

    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)

    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)

    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)

    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)

    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:370)

    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)

    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)

    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)

    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)

    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Are you authenticating via LDAP??

Comment: @HariKrishna--MSFTIdentity it is Azure AD as an OIDC identity provider.